# What is the difference between autoplot function and plot function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, ggfortify

What is the difference between these two functions

```
plot(AP,xlab="Date", ylab = "Passenger numbers (1000's)",main="Air Passenger numbers from 1949 to 1961")

autoplot(AP) + labs(x ="Date", y = "Passenger numbers (1000's)", title="Air Passengers from 1949 to 1961")
```

Comment: `plot` is from base R and `autoplot` is part of the `ggplot2` package. These are two different plotting systems. See for example here for an explanation: https://flowingdata.com/2016/03/22/comparing-ggplot2-and-r-base-graphics/

Comment: What does the difference look like?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of graphical data representation there is not much difference between `graphics::plot` and `ggplot2::autoplot` + `ggfortify` package for time-series plotting. The difference will be obvious if you will start to plot more complex plot (facetting, multiplot, grouping etc.). As for your question please see below:

**graphics::plot**:

```
data(AirPassengers)
AP <- AirPassengers
plot(AP, xlab="Date", ylab = "Passenger numbers (1000's)", main = "Air Passenger data, base")
```

[image: base]

**ggplot2::autoplot**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
data(AirPassengers)
AP <- AirPassengers

autoplot(AP) + 
  labs(x ="Date", y = "Passenger numbers (1000's)", title = "Air Passengers from, ggplot2")
```

[image]